# DHCP wont release allocated IPs

Tags: iptables, routing, router, dhcp

I have a TP-Link td28151 router and I am using DHCP. I need to connect 40 devices to my router by Ethernet.

I have set the count of my clients to 100, and my subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.
I have previously connected 28 of my devices to my router and they worked fine. I connected and disconnected them many times so my router has given every IP address from 1 -100 over times.

Now I want to add the 29th device but it wont get IP. So I went to my routers firmware. in DHCP allocation table, I saw that my router has *strangely) allocated every IP from 1 to 100, though 28 devices are really connected.

Can any body please tell me what I should do to be able to connect my 29th device and get IP from router? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check what your DHCP lease is, the DHCP server may have allocated 100 addresses but it doesn't necessarily mean that they are all on the network at the one time. This is especially the case with transient Wi-Fi devices (such as mobile phones).

I'd suggest flushing your DHCP bindings and/or increasing the allocation space from 100 addresses to something higher. You can double your addressable space by changing the subnet mask down to a 255.255.254.0 or a /23.

Comment: Ok lease time was set to three days, changed it to four hours.
also changed the maximum connections from 100 to 150, but my efforts have been fruitless. so far. I'm going to flush my Router.